# Maven resolves ranges incorrectly

Tags: java, maven

I recently faced with the following problem: on GoCD agents I launch command

```
mvn versions:resolve-ranges
```

against pom file with the following content

```
<properties>
     <myservice.version>[1.21,1.22)</myservice.version>
</properties>
```

And this range was resolved into 1.22.2, which is the latest version on repository but not in range I specified. Maven version is 3.1.1, Java 1.8.0-45.

Later I tried locally the same command against the same pom - and it resolved correctly. Locally I have Maven 3.5.3 and Java 1.8.0-181.

Any idea how that could happen?

Comment: First why are you using such an old Maven version? Furthermore have you defined the version of versions-maven-plugin in your pom file? So have you used the same version in both cases?

Comment: Well that version is devs requirement and it used to work with this setup. And no, versions-maven-plugin version is not defined in pom in both cases. However what difference does it make? Ranges are ranges in all versions

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid mistake, sorry for possibly misleading someone here. Turned out that someone has replaced versions:resolve-ranges goal with versions:update-versions